Determine the convergence radius of the series
suppose:$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n  \   diverges,S_n=a_1+a_2+...+a_n \ .$My question is whether the convergence radius of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n \ and \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}S_nx^n$$are equal?If I add"$a_n\geq0$",it is true.But without"$a_n\geq0$", I can't determine whether it is correct or not.If it isn't correct,give me an example.Thanks!

I believe the answer is "yes". The assumption that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ diverges means that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is less than or equal to $1$. In other words, the singularity of the function $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ that's closest to the origin is somewhere in $[-1,1]$. But then the singularity of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n x^n = \frac1{1-x}A(x)$ that's closest to the origin is the same as the closest singularity of $A(x)$, which means that its radius of convergence is the same.
